# JBoss EAP 6.2 - JSF2.1 - Error reading faces-config.xml file from jars

Tags: jsf-2, annotations, jboss-eap-6, faces-config

I am trying to run JSF2.1 Web Application with JBoss EAP 6.2. But in logs i am getting below error due to which JSF annotations(ex @ManagedBean, JSF Converters, JSF Validators) in jars are not working.

```
Unable to process annotations for url, 
vfs:/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/deployments/my_appl.war/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.5.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  
Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

### I have below structure in my application.

WebApp

- JSF Managed Beans - (They are working with annotations)
- WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
- my_jar.jar
- - JSF Managed Beans - (They are not working with annotations)
- - META-INF/faces-config.xml

Will really appreciate any help on this.

### Things which I have tried so far

Adding below in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Running my application in JBoss EAP 6.1